# Illustrator (*.AI) compatible way to do work?

Tags: osx, graphic-design

I am currently at an internship where I work with a designer to come out with manuals and books. The designer works remotely and there is a lot of sending the files back and forth.

I got the designer to sync+share the file on Google Drive so that I can edit the file as well. The designer works exclusively on Adobe Illustrator which I can't afford to get. (we both use macOS)

Is there a software that will allow me to open and edit `.ai` files without many issues on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit AI files in a Mac with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/), a free, open source vector graphics editor. Inkscape is a professional quality vector graphics software that is used by design professionals and hobbyists worldwide for creating a wide variety of graphics such as illustrations, icons, logos, diagrams, maps and web graphics.